# How to play a List of songs using naudio and c#?

Tags: c#, naudio

I have a problem when I try to play a list of songs, my code does not work.  Only the first few seconds each song plays but I want to play all the contents of each song list:

```
private void Play()
{
    List<Song> songList = ViewModelLocator.Instance.SongListVM.Songs;
    foreach(Song song  in songList)
    {
        audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(song.Path);
        waveOutDevice.Init(audioFileReader);
        waveOutDevice.Play();
    }
}
```

I tried to use a Thread:

```
waveOutDevice.Play();
Thread.Sleep(audioFileReader.TotalTime);
```

but it only hangs.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use call backs aka delegates.

Comment: Not very easy to answer this without seeing more of what you're trying to do but it looks like: a) with this approach you would be playing all of the songs at once. The foreach loop creates an audio player and then plays a song, then does it again for every song in the list. Shouldn't it wait until one song is complete before starting the next? b) I don't see why you're using threading like this but maybe I'm missing something. Looks to me like your Thread.Sleep call just causes the thread to sleep for the length of the song - which is possibly why it hangs.

Comment: I used the thread to stop process or foreach while it playing the song, 
I was using NAudio.Wave library;
 private AudioFileReader audioFileReader;
 private IWavePlayer waveOutDevice;

Answer (score 0):

For me I used this :

```
int song_index=0; // index of the song
private void player_play()
{
        outputdevice.PlaybackStopped += playbackstopped;
        if (outputdevice.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Paused)
        {
                to_play = playlist.Rows[song_index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                audiofile = new AudioFileReader(to_play);
                outputdevice.Init(audiofile);
        }
        outputdevice.Play();
}
// this event occur when the playing file has ended
private void playbackstopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
        song_index++;      // play the next file
        player_play();
}
```